# List index out of range? If statement

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, if-statement

I have a truly puzzling issue
Im using some nested if statements to produce a list, using variables from lists

```
if List1[0] or List2[0] or List3[0] or List4[0] or List5[0] == 'Something':
```

Now my assumption is that it would check for a value in either spot to be my specific word, then continue to the next statement if not, however it stops here.

here's a little bit more of the breakdown so you can see my goal here

```
for i in range(5):
    if List1[0] or List2[0] or List3[0] List4[0] or List5[0] == 'Something':
        SuperList.append('example1, example2, example3')
        if List1[0] == 'Something':
            List1.remove('Something')
        elif List2[0] == 'Something':
            List2.remove('Something')
        elif List3[0] == 'Something':
            List3.remove('Something')
        elif List4[0] == 'Something':
            List4.remove('Something')
        elif List5[0] == 'Something':
            List5.remove('Something')
    elif List1[0] or List2[0] or List3[0] or List4[0] or List5[0] == 'SomethingElse':ECT.....
```

Anyway, i know for certain that all lists 1-5 contain exactly 1 Word, as i had my program print them all too me prior to the long if/nested if function to come

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why are you using a `for` loop?  You need this odd comparison to happen 5 times? Also, you are missing an `or` between `List3` and `List4` on you example code.

Comment: It's actually for a game, in my code i have it so 1 value is in each 5 of the lists. the if statements will stop after they hit something that meets the criteria and jumps out.
Then i need it to take the value that was true and subtract it from the equation, so when it loops again. It can find a new value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what the problem here is that you are only comparing List5[0] to 'Something'. You need to compare 'Something' to each value individually. (As a side note, because you are not comparing all of the values, Python expects a boolean value, while your lists hold string values). 
To fix your problem you could do this for example:

```
if List1[0] == 'Something' or List2[0] == 'Something' or List3[0] == 'Something' or List4[0] == 'Something' or List5[0] == 'Something':
    # The rest of your code here
```

Again, you have to compare each value individually so that they can become booleans. That seems to be the only problem with your code. I hope this cleared it up for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, I knew it had to be something along such lines just didn't know how to apply it.

Comment: Not a problem, my pleasure